# Storing selected product options in a shopping cart in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, shopping-cart, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am building a shopping cart in CakePHP and currently have the following relationships:

- `Product` HABTM (HasAndBelongsToMany) `Options`
- `Cart` HABTM `Products`

Pretty standard? I'm just not sure what to do when a user selects some options for the product and saves it to the cart. Do I add a new model called `CollectionsProductOptions`?

What's the best way to store this kind of data? Should I just serialize an array of selected options and save to the `carts_products` table?

Answer (score 0):

My approach was to try to stick to convention.  I have a cart model, an item model, an option model and a value model (an option can have multiple values).  Once I got it to there, everything fell in to place.  You need to set recursion to "3" but when you read the cart, you get everything perfectly laid out.

I keep my cart products/options separate from my catalog products/options. On the cart side, an option only belongs to one product.  On the catalog side, an option can belong to many products. Your approach may be different.  I do this because options may change and I don't want my old sales information to change.  I do this for all cart tables.  The cart_products table is different than the products table.  The product_options table is different than the options table, etc.